# How to access a django model field in views?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-views

So basically I have a django model which has a Frequency field that I'd like to access inside my views.py file so that I can update it.

```
class Search(models.Model):
   Search_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   Search_User = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
   Frequency = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

What I'm tryin to do is increase the frequency field by 1 instead of creating a new object.

```
        if models.Search.objects.filter(Search_value=search, Search_User=user):
           x = models.Search.objects.filter(Search_value=search, Search_User=user)
           print(x)
        else:
           models.Search.objects.create(Search_value=search, Search_User=user, Frequency=1)
```

This is the logic I use to try to figure it out but the print(x) returns "<QuerySet [<Search: Shirts>]>
". How can I access the Frequency field inside this form so that I can update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [**`.update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) here:

```
from django.db.models import F

#...
if models.Search.objects.filter(Search_value=search, Search_User=user).exists():
   models.Search.objects.filter(Search_value=search, Search_User=user).update(Frequency=F('Frequency')+1)
else:
   models.Search.objects.create(Search_value=search, Search_User=user, Frequency=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can directly loop through, which will be something like:

```py
x = models.Search.objects.filter(Search_value=search, Search_User=user)
for obj in x:
    obj.Frequency += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The fewest queries you can do this in is two. An [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update) query that returns the number of rows updated, if the number of rows is zero then create an entry

```
existing = models.Search.objects.filter(
    Search_value=search,
    Search_User=user
).update(
    Frequency=F('Frequency') + 1
)
if not existing
    models.Search.objects.create(
        Search_value=search,
        Search_User=user,
        Frequency=1
    )
```